# Restart TeamCity server via web interface

Tags: teamcity, restart

Is there a way to restart a TeamCity server running on Windows from its web interface? I haven't found a button or documentation whether this is possible.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

This is [now available in 2017.2](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/What%27s+New+in+TeamCity+2017.2#What%27sNewinTeamCity2017.2-ManagingPluginsfromWebUI) via the Diagnostics page of the admin area:

> Now there is also the server Restart button on the Administration | Diagnostics page.

`/admin/admin.html?item=diagnostics#serverRestart`

[image: Diagnostics page with Restart button highlighted]

Answer (score 29):

Such option is not implemented in TeamCity. Please vote for the issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-34946.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and for escalating this to your issue tracker/wishlist.